# Android app crashes the second time i open it on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, onbackpressed

I wanted to add functionality that closes app when back button is pressed, and it works fine on android 4.2.2 but it crashes when i open it second time on marshmallow. This is my method:

```
@override
public void     onBackPressed(){
Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(a);
}
```

Comment: Please state your question clearly. This is just a statement right now.

Comment: This might not be the best way to close app, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```
@override
public void onBackPressed(){
   this.finishAffinity();
}
```